# Compare a file's contents with command output, then execute command and append file

Tags: bash, command-line, awk

**1. File**

A file `/etc/ssh/ipblock` contains lines that look like this:

```
2012-01-01 12:00 192.0.2.201
2012-01-01 14:15 198.51.100.123
2012-02-15 09:45 192.0.2.15
2012-03-12 21:45 192.0.2.14
2012-04-25 00:15 203.0.113.243
```

**2. Command**

The output of the command `iptables -nL somechain` looks like this:

```
Chain somechain (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  172.18.1.4           anywhere
DROP       all  --  198.51.100.123       anywhere
DROP       all  --  172.20.4.16          anywhere
DROP       all  --  192.0.2.125          anywhere
DROP       all  --  172.21.1.2           anywhere
```

**3. The task at hand**

1. First I would like to get a list A of IP addresses that are existent in the iptables chain (field 4) but not in the file.
2. Then I would like to get a list B of IP addresses that are existent in the file but not in the iptables chain.
3. IP addresses in list A should then be appended to the file in the same style (date, time, IP)
4. IP addresses in list B should then be added to the iptables chain with
   `iptables -A somechain -d IP -j DROP`

**4. Background**

I was hoping to expand my awk-fu so I have been trying to get this to work with an awk script that can be executed without arguments. But I failed.

I know I can get the output from commands with the `getline` command so I was able to get the time and date that way. And I also know that one can read a file using `getline foo < file`. But I have only had many failed attempts to combine this all into a working awk script.

I realise that I could get this to work with an other programming language or a shell script. But can this be done with an awk script that can be ran without arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is almost exactly what you were looking for. Does the job, all in one file, code I guess is pretty much self-explanatory...
Easily adaptable, extendable...

**USAGE:**
`./foo.awk CHAIN ip.file`

**foo.awk:**

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    CHAIN= ARGV[1]
    IPBLOCKFILE = ARGV[2]

    while((getline < IPBLOCKFILE) > 0) {
        IPBLOCK[$3] = 1
    }

    command = "iptables -nL " CHAIN
    command |getline
    command |getline
    while((command |getline) > 0) {
        IPTABLES[$4] = 1
    }
    close(command)

    print "not in IPBLOCK (will be appended):"
    command = "date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'"
    command |getline DATE
    close(command)
    for(ip in IPTABLES) {
        if(!IPBLOCK[ip]) {
            print ip
            print DATE,ip >> IPBLOCKFILE
        }
    }

    print "not in IPTABLES (will be appended):"
    # command = "echo iptables -A " CHAIN " -s " //use for testing 
    command = "iptables -A " CHAIN " -s "
    for(ip in IPBLOCK) {
        if(!IPTABLES[ip]) {
            print ip
            system(command ip " -j DROP")
        }
    }
    exit
}
```

Comment: It's *exactly* what I was looking for. Great demonstration! I see that you run `command |getline` twice, this is to skip the first two lines of header from iptables, correct?
Also, I never expected to run the whole program only in `BEGIN`. :)

Comment: referring `getline` - you're right. It is not required to do all in `BEGIN` - you could read the input_file but then you would anyway need `END` pattern - So better all in one place.:)

Comment: Ok. I had to make one small adjustment; after a couple of iterations I nearly got blocked. :)

Answer (score 1):

Doing 1&3:

```
comm -13 <(awk '{print $3}' /etc/ssh/ipblock | sort) <(iptables -nL somechain | awk '/\./{print $4}' | sort) | xargs -n 1 echo `date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M'` >> /etc/ipblock
```

Doing 2&4:

```
comm -13 <(awk '{print $3}' /etc/ssh/ipblock | sort) <(iptables -nL somechain | awk '/\./{print $4}' | sort) | xargs -n 1 iptables -A somechain -d IP -j DROP
```

The command is constructed of the following building blocks:

1. Bash process substitution feature: it is somewhat similar to pipe features, but is often used when a program requires two or more input files in its arguments/options. Bash creates `fifo` file, which basically "contains" the output of a given command. In our case the output will be ip adresses.
2. Then output of `awk` scripts is passed to `comm` program, and both `awk` scripts are pretty simple: they just print ip address. In first case all ips are contained in third column(hence `$3`), and in the second case all ips are contained in the fourth column, but it is neccessary to get rid of column header("destination" string), so simple regex is used `/\./`: it filters out all string that doesn't contain a dot.
3. `comm` requires both inputs to be sorted, thus output of `awk` is sorted using `sort`
4. Now `comm` program receives both lists of ip addresses. When no options are given, it prints three columns: lines unique to FILE1, lines unique to FILE2, lines in both files. By passing `-23` to it we get only lines unique to FILE1. Similarly, passing `-13` makes it output lines unique to FILE2.
5. `xargs` is basically a "foreach" loop in bash, it executes a given command per each input line(thanks to `-n 1`). The second  is pretty obvious(it is the desired `iptables` invocation). The second one isn't complicated too: it just makes `date` to output current time in proper format.

Comment: Sure! BTW, I'd prefer your way, but I just didn't think about this

Comment: Cool. I wasn't aware of `comm`, thanks for pointing it out! It's a cool method :)

Comment: `Comm` is surely a nice program. I was glad to help you